# Rapidjson giving validation success even when required field is missing

Tags: jsonschema, rapidjson

I was expecting rapidjson to give a validation error as my json file doesn't include one of the 'required' field mentioned in the schema. However, due to some reasons this doesn't happen.

dbconf.json(json file)

```
{
        "MAX_CONNECTION_PER_HOST":20,
        "QUEUE_IO_SIZE":10485,
        "Garbage":50000
}
```

Here's the test code along with the schema.

```
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/error/en.h"
#include "rapidjson/schema.h"
#include <rapidjson/stringbuffer.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

const char g_plJsonSchema[]="{\
                             \"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",\
                             \"title\": \"Schema\",\
                             \"description\": \"JSON schema for validating Json file\",\
                             \"type\": \"object\",\
                             \"properties\": {\
                             \"MAX_CONNECTION_PER_HOST\": { \"type\": \"number\" },\
                              \"QUEUE_IO_SIZE\": { \"type\": \"number\" },\
                              \"REQUEST_LOW_WATER_MARK\": { \"type\": \"number\" },\
\"required\": [\
\"MAX_CONNECTION_PER_HOST\",\
\"QUEUE_IO_SIZE\",\
\"REQUEST_LOW_WATER_MARK\"\
]\
      }\
}";

int main()

{
        rapidjson::Document l_peerAddSchemaDoc, l_peerAddDataDoc;
        l_peerAddSchemaDoc.Parse(g_plJsonSchema);
        if(l_peerAddSchemaDoc.HasParseError())
        {
                printf("JSON schema file is not a valid JSON file\n");
                return -1;
        }
        std::ifstream l_confDataIStream("dbconf.json");
        std::string l_confDataIStreamStr((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(l_confDataIStream)),(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
        l_peerAddDataDoc.Parse(l_confDataIStreamStr.c_str());


        rapidjson::SchemaDocument l_schemaDocument(l_peerAddSchemaDoc);
        rapidjson::SchemaValidator l_SchemaValidator(l_schemaDocument);

        if(!l_peerAddDataDoc.Accept(l_SchemaValidator))
        {
                rapidjson::StringBuffer sb;
                l_SchemaValidator.GetInvalidSchemaPointer().StringifyUriFragment(sb);
                printf("Invalid schema: %s\n", sb.GetString());
                printf("Invalid keyword: %s\n", l_SchemaValidator.GetInvalidSchemaKeyword());
                sb.Clear();
                l_SchemaValidator.GetInvalidDocumentPointer().StringifyUriFragment(sb);
                printf("Invalid document: %s\n", sb.GetString());
        }
else
printf("\nJson file validated with the given schema successfully\n");

        return 0;
}
```

I get the following output

```
Json file validated with the given schema successfully
```

Comment: Thanks for your question. Would you be able to provide your JSON Schema and JSON instace outside of your code please? This allows us to check if there is an issue with the schema itself or not first. Thanks.

Comment: Json file is already outside the code. Just remove the backslash from g_plJsonSchema to get the schema.

Comment: {"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#", "title": "Schema", "description": "JSON schema for validating Json file", "type": "object", "properties": { "MAX_CONNECTION_PER_HOST": { "type": "number" }, "QUEUE_IO_SIZE": { "type": "number" }, "REQUEST_LOW_WATER_MARK": { "type": "number" }, "required": [ "MAX_CONNECTION_PER_HOST", "QUEUE_IO_SIZE", "REQUEST_LOW_WATER_MARK"] } }

Comment: I just hope I've not done any mistakes while removing backslashes.

Comment: For future reference, it's better to edit your question to add code blocks rather than use comments, however, this was OK to work with =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is `required` should be at the root level, and not inside `properties`. In fact, you currently have an invalid schema, as all values of keys inside `properties` should be objects only.

```
{
  "$schema": "json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Schema",
  "description": "JSON schema for validating Json file",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "MAX_CONNECTION_PER_HOST": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "QUEUE_IO_SIZE": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "REQUEST_LOW_WATER_MARK": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "required": [
      "MAX_CONNECTION_PER_HOST",
      "QUEUE_IO_SIZE",
      "REQUEST_LOW_WATER_MARK"
    ]
}
```

I validated the schema against the instance using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net for testing.